# Web page not loading properly on iPod 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ipod-touch

In our app we've got an ordinary `UIWebView` showing a web page. And it works perfectly on any type of device except `iPod 5`. When being executed on that device the page is showed just partly, without images, just few lines of text and that's it. The more interesting is that the same thing happens even if you open this page in `Safari` on this `iPod`. We've already tried using different types of `NSURLRequestCachePolicy` and also using custom `NSURLCache` objects but all in vain. Can anybody suggest a solution?